# how much could my performance decrease if I have to query into a DB with 100K rows in Wordpress?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am using wordpress for a big information site, its working fine, but now I have to populate some custom fields, each field creates an entry on the `postmeta` table.

As far as I know, that table is used to storage all other post's information, attachments and so on, my question is, when I will request for example, a normal post with an attachment file or something not heavy, due the query will have to look into a table with 100k entries, will it be slow? would cause a problem?

I know this question is very subjective, but according someone's experience, could adivce me about it? How much the performance of the DBMS would dicrease?

Thanks.

I have this structure

[image: DB diagram]

and here are the descriptions of the tables

> wp_postmeta
>    Each post features information called the meta data and
>   it is stored in the wp_postmeta. Some plugins may add their own
>   information to this table.
>
> wp_posts
>   The core of the WordPress data is the posts. It is stored in
>   the wp_posts table. Also Pages and navigation menu items are stored in
>   this table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the query. If you're going to do a *full table scan*, expect a massive performance hit. If all you're going to do is a *primary key lookup*, the performance penalty will be negligible.

Comment: well, according the table, it has a post_id reference, seems like it is not a foreign key, but I guess it should look for this index, what do you think?

Comment: If you update your question with the table layout (create table statement) and the query you want to run, I'll analyze it for you.

Comment: I see the structure, but what's the query? Also, can you post `create table` statements instead of the image? If the query is of the format `select * from wp_postmeta where post_id=1` you'll be fine performance-wise

Comment: yes, for example, if you upload an image it will create a postmeta entry with a text field named "file" and will look for it when I call the post (i think it does automatic with every post), no so much problem with that, but some posts might add 40 entries there, and yes, the query is always select * from wp_postmeta where post_id=1, u think will be fine with over 100,000 entires on post_meta ?

Comment: If you have a decent index (in this case it looks like you do) it doesn't matter much how many rows you have in the table.

Answer (score 0):

wp_postmeta has inefficient indexes. Here is a discussion of such, plus recommended cures:

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta